# Different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra? for $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exceptional-isomorphisms

An exceptional Lie algebra is a complex simple Lie algebra whose Dynkin diagram is of exceptional (nonclassical) type. There are exactly five of them: $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$, ${\mathfrak {f}}_{4}$,${\mathfrak {e}}_{6}$,
${\mathfrak {e}}_{7}$, ${\mathfrak {e}}_{8}$; their respective dimensions are 14, 52, 78, 133, 248.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_Lie_algebra

Usually, given a Lie algebra,

> there could be different Lie groups associated to the same given Lie algebras.

It is commonly say the Lie groups of given Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$, ${\mathfrak {f}}_{4}$,${\mathfrak {e}}_{6}$,
${\mathfrak {e}}_{7}$, ${\mathfrak {e}}_{8}$ are $G_2$, $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$

However, do we have other and different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$, ${\mathfrak {f}}_{4}$,${\mathfrak {e}}_{6}$,
${\mathfrak {e}}_{7}$, ${\mathfrak {e}}_{8}$?

For example, the $SO(N)$ and $Spin(N)$ can have the same Lie algebra ${\mathfrak {so}}_{n}$, but different Lie groups because $Spin(N)/(\mathbb{Z}/2)=SO(N)$.

Comment: Probably you mean to refer to $E_n$ with $n=6,7,8$ throughout, not $n=7,8,9$ There is an $E_9$ entity but it's not finite-dimensional, etc.

Comment: yes typos thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups will answer this

Comment: Crosspost to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369887/