# Centers of exceptional Lie groups for Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Centers of exceptional Lie groups

It is commonly say the Lie groups of given exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$, ${\mathfrak {f}}_{4}$,${\mathfrak {e}}_{6}$,
${\mathfrak {e}}_{7}$, ${\mathfrak {e}}_{8}$ are $G_2$, $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$. What the centers $Z(G)$ of these Lie groups $G$?

Note that: In a previous question, I also asked whether there are more and different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra? for $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_Lie_algebra and [Different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra? for $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3799800/141334)

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0431.pdf) for the centres, for various different Lie groups with a given exceptional simple Lie algebra.

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369887/